# SQL query that calculates percentages based on the values of one column and at the same time groups the results based on the values of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with 3 columns (email (varchar),department (varchar),status(varchar) ).
Some sample data would be :

```
email,department,status
john@example.com,Finance,passed
Nick@example.com,Finance,passed
alice@example.com,Finance,not_started
william@example.com,Production,passed
bill@example.com,Production,passed
Nikole@example.com,Management,not_started
joe@example.com,Management,not_started
```

and i am trying to write a query. The results of the query will be presented in a Grafana dashboard. My goal is to have a per department report with percentages based on the "status" field which can only have to values (passed or not_started).
something like:

Finance: passed x%
Production: passed x%
Management: passed x%

Or in other words what is the percent per department that have passed.

What i have so far accomplished is to have the results only for one department but i cannot combine the results for every department in a single query.

My working code is :

```
SELECT status, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() as "Percent"
FROM table 
where Department = 'Production'
GROUP BY status
```

Any advice given would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation, like: `COUNT(case when status = 'finance' then 1 end), COUNT(case when status = 'production' then 1 end)` etc

Comment: Personally, as well, for percentages like I like to use `AVG`. For example `AVG(CASE status WHEN 'Passed' THEN 1. ELSE 0. END)` gives you the percentage passed, and as a decimal (i.e. 0.57). Then you don't need any of that multiplying or division.

Comment: Is the set of `department` values static or subject to change? Do you expect the results to be one row per `department` or a single row with a column for each `department`?

Comment: @HABO that is what i was about to explain. The values of the column "department" are more than 50. This means that a static declaration of every possible value would make the query huge or impractical. I was thinking maybe an extra group by clause but i can't figure it out.

Comment: By using the data that i have provided above the expected results should be: Finance passed 66,6% , Production passed 100% , management passed 0%

Comment: Well, then you can use dynamic pivot / conditional aggregations. 99% of questions on sql-server tag are related to that so just search for those terms. Also, the idea is not to keep providing crumbs of info but rather write it out ahead of time